# Send mail Based on drop down list c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to make an application where emails can be sent to users based on the choice (Service Type) from a drop down list. My code doesn't work as I deterred the Number type based on the service type as shown in the SQL query. My question is how can I send emails based on the service for each number I've got? Any help would be appreciated.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindReportsTypeDropDown();
        }
    }

  public class EmailSend
    {

        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string Service  { get; set; }

    }

    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //try
        // {
        int Service = 0;

            // Connection String 
            string ConnectionString = @"Data Source= (localdb)\......";
            SqlDataReader reader;
            String SendMessage = "Select Number FROM services where   
             ServiceType = 1 or ServiceType =2";
            using (SqlConnection MyCon = new 
        SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                MyCon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SendMessage, MyCon);
                ArrayList EmailArray = new ArrayList();
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                var Email = new List<EmailSend>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    Email.Add(new EmailSend
                    {

                        Number = Convert.ToString(reader["Numnber"]),
                        SErviceType = 
               Convert.ToString(reader["ServiceType"]),

                    });
                }



                foreach (EmailSend email in Email)
                {
                    // Email Config

                    const string username = "mail";
                    const string password = "pass";
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    MailAddress fromadd = new MailAddress("email", "pass");
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.Port = 587;

                    mail.From = fromadd;
                    mail.To.Add("mail");
                    mail.Subject = ("subject ");

                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    mail.Body = "<p>Hi </p> " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email.Number) + "<br/> <p>Please find the the details of all reports!</p> </br> <p> Date of Sending the reports: " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(email.ServiceType) + "</p> <br/>"; 
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password);
                    smtp.Send(mail);


                }
            }
        }
```

Drop Down List

```
  protected void BindReportsTypeDropDown()
    {
        ReportType.DataSource = GetData(" SELECT Number FROM Services where 
        ServiceType= 1 OR ServiceType= 2");
        ReportType.DataTextField = " ServiceType";
        ReportType.DataValueField = " ServiceType";
        ReportType.DataBind();
    }
    private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
       string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;

                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    return dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```